# Can't add jar to palette in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, components, javabeans

I'm currently studying Java Beans and I am unable to import my .jar into a NetBeans palette. I'm working with AWT components at the moment FYI.

Here are the steps I've taken :

- Take a NetBeans project with a Bean which is known to work on
  another PC
- Add the project to my NetBeans workspace
- Create a new compiled and cleaned .jar file
- Import the .jar file : tools > palette > Swing/AWT Components > Add from JAR > select the JAR in the "dist" folder in the NetBeans project > select the component I want to add > Select the palette folder I want to add it to > "Finish" > "Close".

After doing all of this, nothing happens and no new component is added.

Has anyone come across this type of issue ? If so how have you managed to get this working ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetBeans is seems to bugging out here but I've found a work around which consists in importing the jar file as a library into the project.